# (Excel) Select value from column based on highest sum value of another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, match, criteria

I want to figure out based on the example below which month has the highest cumulative hours. I understand selecting a value based on another, but not when I still have to find that value what per say, which would be the sum of hours for each month.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few way of doing this perhaps for readability one could try using `GROUPBY()`:

[image]

---

```
=@GROUPBY(A2:A12,B2:B12,MAX,,0,-2)
```

---

Or,

```
=LET(α, A2:A12, @SORT(UNIQUE(HSTACK(α,SUMIF(α,α,B2:B12))),2,-1))
```

---

Or, The following will work with `Excel 2021`

```
=INDEX(SORT(UNIQUE(CHOOSE({1,2},A2:A12,SUMIF(A2:A12,A2:A12,B2:B12))),2,-1),1,1)
```

---

Answer (score 2):

With traditional functions:

Add an additional column in this case column N with the formula:

`=MAX(SUMIF(L$51:L$66,L51,M$51:M$66))`  drag down

and the result cell:

`=INDEX(L51:M66,MATCH(MAX(N51:N66),N51:N66),1)`

[image]